# Integrating Admob in my application

Tags: android, admob

I am new to android.currently i am using eclipse with android 4.0 api 14.Before integrating admob all works well.after integrating admob a error is display 
"no resource identifier found for attribute adsize" and "no resource identifier found for attribute adUnitId" in main.xml

I found many similar question but can't solve it.

my main.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RootLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/adLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_publisher_id"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

main activity.java

```
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;

    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.easywebapp"
android:installLocation="auto"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.asd.Splashscreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.asd.Image"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_image" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code seems to be fine.Check google play service library is included if included verify its path.

Answer (score 0):

try the below link
[refer here](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-how-to-integrate-google-admob-in-your-app/)

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
```